# Writing a function that adds two matrices

Tags: c++

```
void add_matrices(int matrix_1 [m][n], int matrix_2 [m][n], int matrix_3 [m][n], int num_rows, int num_cols)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++)
  {
    for (int j = 0; i < num_cols; j++)
    {
        matrix_3[i][j] = matrix_1[i][j] + matrix_2[i][j];
    }
  }
} // end of function that adds two matrices
```

I'm trying to write a function that adds two matrices (2-D arrays). Here is the snippet of code from my program where I define the function. I can post the rest of my code but figured it might be easier to look at.

When I run the code it says "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS" on the line that starts with matrix_3. I think the issue lies in the parameters I'm passing to the function. Matrices 1 and 2 are filled in the main and matrix 3 is created in the main but empty.

Comment: Don't you want to pass matrix_3 by reference ? (I'm not sure it will solve the problem but ..)

Comment: Arrays are automatically passed by reference so I don't think that's the issue

Comment: Where are `m` and `n` defined? Is this a template function? Keep in mind your `matrix_3` argument will be thrown away when this function ends without actually doing anything useful as Victor points out.

Comment: Yup .. I ignored it !
I've been raced by tadman : why to pass num_rows and num_cols if m and n seems to be template arguments ?

Comment: I'd also say that code like this is very anti-C++. Typically you'd use a `std::vector` to store data for this within a simple templated wrapper class and write `operator+` to deal with the addition case. That means `a = b + c` works for any given set of compatible matrix instances.

Comment: I'm using outputting matrix_3 in the main function and since it's passed by reference, matrix_3 in main gets this value.

Comment: @Steve Arrays decay to pointers and thus actually passed by value.  All of that stuff going on with your parameters are merely pointers, not actual arrays being passed, even with the `[m][n]` syntax being used.  A C++ solution would be to use `std::array<std::array<int, m>,n>` (if `m`and `n` are constants), or if the dimensions are determined at runtime or very large, `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` and the vector sized appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

`for (int j = 0; i < num_cols; j++)`

This should be:

`for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++)`

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't catch that. Thanks!